# How do I call a method of the app delegate from a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

**Situation:**
I am using the "Navigation Based Application" project template. And my root view controller (UIViewController) needs to call a method of the app delegate.

**Question:**
How do I call a method of the app delegate from a UIViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] someMethod];
```

Or in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` set a static member that is returned by a static method of your delegate class.

```
+(id) shared { return sAppDelegate; }
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)a { sAppDelegate = self; }
```

Or just use a global without the wrapper.